# Covariance is Equal to Zero

Tags: covariance

If Co-variance (X, Y) = 0, does this necessarily mean that X and Y are independent?

I have read in previous posts that Co-variance equal to 0 implies that (1) X and Y are independent AND (2) X and Y could be independent, but are not necessarily so.  These two interpretations, however, are obviously contradictory.

Comment: Which previous posts?

Answer (score 0):

There was a Soviet paper in the 60's which formally introduced *spherically invariant processes*. If X(t) is such process, then

X(t) and X(s) are uncorrelated   <=====>   X(t) and X(s) are independent.

An example of spherically invariant process is multiplicative Gaussian mixture:

X(t) = A * Z(t),

where Z(t) is a Gaussian process and A is some random variable... Generally speaking, 0 correlation does not imply independence. Example:

Y = X * N(0,1),

where X and N(0,1) are independent. Notice that Corr[X,Y] = 0 but X and Y are codependent.